# How detect if message body is TNEF format (winmail.dat)?

Tags: php, tnef, winmail.dat

How *detect/check* if message body is [tnef](/questions/tagged/tnef) format (winmail.dat) using PHP?

I don't want to decode, just want to check. I using `imap_fetchbody` and `imap_body` for get BODY, I need get mimetype (or like) for check if is "tnef format", like this:

```
if (in_array($bodyMimeType, array('application/tnef', 'application/x-tnef', 'application/ms-tnef'))) {
    //Decode
}
```

I tried:

```
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $messageId, FT_UID);
echo 'sub-type:', $structure->subtype, PHP_EOL;
echo 'encoding:', $structure->encoding, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: And what did what you tried produce?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Perhaps I have not expressed myself well. You know TNEF format (used by MS Exchange)?

Comment: Hi, let us know if you got your answer.

Comment: @sulaimansudirman Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to know without decoding, I'm decoding it and check the status if it is successful using `exec()`, `exec("tnef {$datfile} 2>&1", $output, $status)`, if it is successfully decoded, `$status` will be 0.

Comment: The problem with such a solution is that it is not actually in PHP, it is an external software that I would need to upload to the server to run, of course I agree that it is a solution, only it is not in PHP, which complicates a lot of sharing a code and project. I hope that the PHP IMAP API has some support on this, I need to study it. thanks anyway, your solution will probably work for someone else.